# AbstractController ActionNotFound for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working. Whenever I try to register a User, I get this error & it says I probably didn't wrap my routes in `devise_scope :user; ...; end;`

My registrations controller:

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  respond_to :json

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      login(resource)

      render status: 200,
             json: resource,
             serializer: CurrentUserSerializer,
             root: "user",
             meta: { success: true,
                     info: "Registered" }
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity,
             json: { errors: resource.errors.full_messages }
    end
  end

  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

The piece of my routes controller that matters:

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_scope :user do
        post   'registrations' => 'registrations#create', as: 'register'
        post   'sessions'      => 'sessions#create',      as: 'login'
        delete 'sessions'      => 'sessions#destroy',     as: 'logout'
      end
    end
end
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `devise_for, skip => :all` to add the resource mappings before using `devise_scope` to declare your custom routes, like so:

```
devise_for :users, skip: :all
devise_scope :user do
  # custom routes here
end
```

For reference, this is discussed here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2840#issuecomment-67783871